# Bayesian update from uniform prior to uniform posterior ?!?

Tags: game-theory, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I was working through a signaling game problem recently and the proof suggested the following:

Actor A has a type: $\ \mathscr{t} \sim Uniform[-1,1]$

Actor A gives signal $\pi^*$ that perfectly seperates types at $\pi^{*}$.
In other words, $pr(\pi^*|\mathscr{t}\in [-1,\pi^*])=1\ \&\ pr(\pi^*|\mathscr{t}\in [\pi^*,1])=0$ (this is the likelihood)

Actor B observes $\pi^*$, yielding posterior beliefs about actor A: $\mathscr{t} \sim Uniform[-1,\pi^*]$.

My question is as follows. It appears that this process, as i read it, has the same prior and posterior distributions (uniform), yet the likelihood distribution is unspecified and the uniform is not a conjugate prior for any common distribution. By my reasoning, the posterior distribution is not straightforwardly uniform since it is formed from a non-conjugate prior. Am I missing something here? Does it make sense to say $\mathscr{t}|\pi^{*} \ \sim Uniform[-1,\pi^*]$ or should some other distribution be specified? Alternatively is it possible that the answer to the problem contains an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem with the answer. Bayes formula:

$$
p(t|\pi^*) \propto p(\pi^*|t)p(t).
$$

Since $p(\pi^*|t)$ is $1$ only when $t\in [-1, \pi^*]$ and $0$ otherwise, you get the resulting posterior.

The posterior is clearly not uniform on $[-1,1]$; you're misquoting the result on conjugate distributions. Player $B$ knows player $A$ signals only when $A$'s type is below $\pi^*$, and he updates accordingly

Comment: Strictly speaking, a full statistical specification of the model would state $p(signal|t)$ and $p(no \;signal|t)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but maybe i'm still missing something. the posterior is $\mathscr{t}\sim [-1,\pi^*]$, and my question is as to whether this is a uniform distribution.

Comment: As to the statistical specification, I think I understand the statement, but it could/should be infered that $p(t\in [-1,\pi^*]|\pi^*)=1, p(t\in [-1,\pi^*]|\neg\pi^*)=0$ since $p(t\in [\pi^*,1]|\pi^*)=0$. And either way, does that change anything about the question -- I am genuinely asking this (I know that internet comments can come off as defensive and rude, but that's meant to be my tone here)

Comment: As I said in the answer, the posterior is not uniform. The model is fully specified, implicitly, in econ language. I was just pointing out how a statistician would describe it. It doesn't change the answer.

Comment: ah, i see, that is very helpful, thanks.